# grid view control in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have one grid view control in my asp.net web application. For example i have data grid as 10 rows and 8 columns in fixed size. I want When the data comes to grid view more than 10 rows means the scroll bar will appear to display and not the size of the data grid exceed. How can I do . I use the following source

```
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" 
                    HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

If anyone can help to me its really appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
<div style = "overflow : scroll;">
     <asp:GridView>Your GridView</asp:GridView>
</div>
```

hope it helped.

Comment: Hi added the panel for my aspx page and added the grid view inside the code and set panel scrollbars=auto. Its work successfull.
I used the following code.
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="280px" 
                       Width="558px" ScrollBars="Auto" HorizontalAlign="Center">
 <asp:GridView ID="dataGrid">mygridview</asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>.

Answer (score 1):

Put your grid in a fixed size div element, when the content size exceeds the length of the div it will generate a scroll bar.  If you want to control the scroll bar, use the css attribute "overflow".

Comment: Hi added the panel for my aspx page and added the grid view inside the code and set panel scrollbars=auto. Its work successfull.
I used the following code.
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="280px" 
                       Width="558px" ScrollBars="Auto" HorizontalAlign="Center">
 <asp:GridView ID="dataGrid">mygridview</asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>.

Comment: Great job, just as a note... Your "asp:Panel" generates a html "div" along with a little "extra" info like view state.  If you all you want is a fixed size div to trigger the scroll bars, I would usually opt for the standard HTML div instead of a asp:Panel.